# Create from DateFrame plot - empty plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

i something don't understand and have some question.
Thats my data after processing:

```
     year   date   power
0    2019  01-01  43.611
1    2019  01-02  40.811
2    2019  01-03  14.491
3    2019  01-04  12.649
4    2019  01-05   7.295
..    ...    ...     ...
726  2020  12-27   0.246
727  2020  12-28  10.500
728  2020  12-29  24.669
729  2020  12-30   0.000
730  2020  12-31   0.000

[731 rows x 3 columns]
```

I count power for every single day. Next to wanna change this dataframe into one graph with 2 plots (for 2019 and 2020 year).

After thix code i get output it:

```
ax = plt.gca()

year_data_2019 = wind_power_data[wind_power_data['year'] == '2019']
year_data_2019.plot(kind='line',x='date',y='power', ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

[Graph 1 - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Qt7A.png)

Next to when create single for 2020 year graph code:

```
ax = plt.gca()

year_data_2020 = wind_power_data[wind_power_data['year'] == '2020']
year_data_2020.plot(kind='line',x='date',y='power', ax=ax)
print(year_data_2020 )
plt.show()
```

output:

```
     year   date   power
365  2020  01-01  10.553
366  2020  01-02   0.045
367  2020  01-03   4.865
368  2020  01-04  70.155
369  2020  01-05  11.534
..    ...    ...     ...
726  2020  12-27   0.246
727  2020  12-28  10.500
728  2020  12-29  24.669
729  2020  12-30   0.000
730  2020  12-31   0.000
```

and my graph looks like : (i have not idea why)

[Graph 2 - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKoFd.png)

I want connect them with one and ofc that 2th will show correct date. After connect them both i get:

```
ax = plt.gca()
year_data_2020 = wind_power_data[wind_power_data['year'] == '2020']
year_data_2020.plot(kind='line',x='date',y='power',ax=ax)
year_data_2019 = wind_power_data[wind_power_data['year'] == '2019']
year_data_2019.plot(kind='line',x='date', y='power',ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[Graph 3 - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBzY0.png)

My question is. Why graph 2 show those not correct data?
how to connect them both into one ?
I saw some example and issue is that i should change my dataframe into something like :

```
     date   2019    2020
0    01-01  43.611  20.13
```

So i get the column 'date' date for both? even if 01-01 was the same before but not the same row???

Comment: there is probably some data point in the 2020 data, which has a astronomical high power value, such that the other values seem small (flat). As the scale of the 2020 plot has the 1e8 scale. Can you show all values from december 2020?

Comment: year  - 2020 , date - 12-23, power - 1.440893e+08. You are right 23 december showing huge number

Answer (score 1):

You have one very high value in your dataset.
Either eliminate this datapoint or set the `ylim` parameter in your plot to only show a specific range.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html

To not plot the datapoint, you could restrict the data to every row that is within n times the standard deviation. For example

```
year_data_2020[year_data_2020.power < year_data_2020.power.std()*3].plot(kind='line',x='date',y='power', ax=ax)
```

Comment: Thank you, 23 december showing very big number and ur solution works.

Comment: have like add question - what happen with 28 february ? like 2020 is a leap year when 2019 not so python will ignore this day for 2019 ? or just put value 0 ?

Comment: Missing values are 0 on your plot. You probably want to change your data set before plotting. Have a look at merge and fillna. You probably want to have one column for each year.